# Google Chrome shows error messagebox every time it starts

Tags: google-chrome, user-profiles

I removed Google Chrome 10.x dev version, and installed 8.x stable version again.

After installing 8.x, chrome always shows this message box, every time it starts.

> Your profile can not be used because it is from a newer version of Google Chrome.
>
> Some features may be unavailable. Please specify a different profile directory or use a newer version of Chrome.

What profile does it say. How to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need to delete 'Web Data' files from Dev Version. 
Go and Launch Windows Explorer. Navigate to

`C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

and make sure you enabled the 'show hidden files' features via Folder Options.

Locate the file called web data. Delete it. Then, try to lunch again . Hope it helps. =)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Linux. But you were right. I deleted the folder and it works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using LMDE, I found web data after unhiding files (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>) under `$HOME/.config/google-chrome`.

Search for web data using Nautilus (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>). Delete the web data file, restart Chrome, and the error message is gone.